# await doesn't work within async, could anyone take a look please

Tags: ionic-framework

```
async addTransaction() {
this.ref = this.db.list('transactions', ref => ref.orderByChild('month'));
await this.ref.push(this.transaction).then(() => {
  this.transaction = {
    value: 0,
    expense: false,
    month: 0,
  };
  let toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: 'New transaction has been added!',
    duration: 3000
  });
  toast.present()
```

});
  }

There error says await has to be used within a async function and it does. I dont know why it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

For await to work, the calling function needs to have `async` before it. In your case, the calling function is the `callback`, so please modify your code as below

```
async addTransaction() {
  this.ref = this.db.list('transactions', ref => ref.orderByChild('month'));
  await this.ref.push(this.transaction).then(async() => {
    this.transaction = {
      value: 0,
      expense: false,
      month: 0,
    };
    let toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'New transaction has been added!',
      duration: 3000
    });
    toast.present()
  });
}
```